# Adding an array in jQuery and pass to controller

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, model-view-controller

I created an array like so

```
obj={}
 obj['id'] = jQuery(this).attr("id");
 obj['slotNum'] = tNumber;
```

I need to add this to an array and send it to controller via ajax and access this array in controller in MVC. Can you please advice? I tries creating

```
var arr=[]; 
arr.push(obj)
```

When I put it in alert, I can't see any values. Am I putting it write and how to pass the above array to MVC controller and read it.

Comment: What does `this` refer to? What is the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj` is an object, not an array.

You can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert your array of objects into a string which can be sent in an ajax request:

```
var strArr = JSON.stringify( arr );
```

Then assign `strArr` a parameter name in your ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ....,
    .......
    data: {
        mydata: strArr,
        ....
    },
    ....
});
```

Comment: Object works like an hash table, `obj['id']` or `obj.id` works the same. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maremp/wyhhykd4/1/) to prove I'm correct.